# ¿Cómo sumar horas con JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html5, time

Tengo el siguiente problema, necesito sumar horas :

Mi primer input aqui es donde obtengo el tiempo a calcular

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>tiempo aprox</label>
    <input type="text" name="tiempoap" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $row['tiempoap']; ?>" readonly>
  </div>
```

El código de arriba muestra un input con valor "5 horas 43 minutos" el cual se muestra en la pagina por medio de AJAX y tengo este otro input

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <span class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Hora de salida</span>
    <input type="time" name="horaSalida" class="form-control" required="required">
  </span>
</div>
```

El cual aquí elijo la hora en este caso seria "09:00 pm", lo que necesito es que se sumen estos dos tiempos y el resultado me lo de en este input

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <span class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Hora de llegada</span>
    <input type="time" name="horaLlegada" class="form-control" required="required">
  </span>
</div>
```

tomando en cuenta que si existe el caso de que el valor sea "1 dia 2 horas 30 minutos" tambien se sumaria el dia a una fecha que tambien escojo el codigo del input de la fecha seria esta

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">Fecha de llegada</span>
    <input type="date" name="fechaLlegada" class="form-control" required="required">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Añade por favor mas informacion a tu pregunta, algunos ejemplos y trozos de codigo

Comment: espero ser lo mas claro posible

Comment: El valor `$row['tiempoap']` es un string? que contiene la descripcion tal cual del tiempo (N horas M Minutos)?... si es asi, creo que seria mas sencillo manejar los valores N y M separados y al mostrarlo (en el input) darle el formato adecuado

Comment: Asi es, el valor de "tiempoap" es un string ya definido y lo presenta asi: "5 horas 43 minutos", como podria separar estos valores

Comment: Tambien puedes recoger los valores con jquery pasarlos a minutos, hacer las funciones que necesites (resta, suma...) y luego lo vuelves a pasar a horas/dias y lo imprimes.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) para manejar fechas (y horas).

`moment().add(1, 'hours').format('HH:mm');`

Así le agregas horas que desees a la hora que hayas escogido. Suponiendo que escogiste 9pm, lo conviertes a fecha de hoy y luego le das sumar las horas que escogiste antes.

`moment(hora_escogida).add(1, 'hours').format('HH:mm');`

Answer (score 0):

No soy experto en PHP y desconozo funciones del mismo, pero basando el ejemplo haciendolo en JS intentare explicar una solucion.

```
var tiempo = $row['tiempoap'];
//separas la cadena en un arreglo
tiempo = tiempo.split(" ");
//obtienes los valores que necesitas
var hora = tiempo[0];
var minutos = tiempo[2];

//esta es tu hora que viene del servidor(N horas M minutos)
var fechaHoy = new Date(2017, 0, 1, hora, minutos, 0);
```

Ahora lo que tendrias que hacer es convertir la segunda cadena en `Date` y hacer la suma y obetener la respectiva diferencia.

Espero darte una idea a tu solucion, saludos.

Comment: `$row['tiempo']` no puede ser llamado del lado del cliente. `<?php ... ?>` es para indicar que debe realizarse un cálculo antes de que la página sea servida.

Answer (score -2):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Sumar Horas</title>
<script>
function calcular(campo1,campo2,destino){
f=campo1.form;
campos=new Array(campo1.name,campo2);
horatotale=new Array(0,0,0);
for(b=0;b<campos.length;b++){
horas=f[campos[b]].value.split(":");
for(a=0;a<3;a++){
horas[a]=(isNaN(parseInt(horas[a])))?0:parseInt(horas[a])
horatotale[a]+=horas[a]; // Suma o resta según prefieras en este caso suma 
}
}
horatotal=new Date()
horatotal.setHours(horatotale[0]);
horatotal.setMinutes(horatotale[1]);
horatotal.setSeconds(horatotale[2]);

f[destino].value=horatotal.getHours()+":"+horatotal.getMinutes()+":"+horatotal.getSeconds();

}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="#" onsubmit="calcular(this);return false">
<input type="text" name="hora1"  onblur="calcular(this,'hora2','horatotal')" /> - 
<input type="text" name="hora2" onblur="calcular(this,'hora1','horatotal')" /> 
= <input type="text" name="horatotal" /> <input type="submit" value="calcular" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" name="pepe"  onblur="calcular(this,'juan','horatotal2')" /> - 
<input type="text" name="juan" onblur="calcular(this,'pepe','horatotal2')" /> 
= <input type="text" name="horatotal2" /> <input type="submit" value="calcular" />


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Ejecutar ejemplo [Aqui](http://www.cubicfactory.com/jseditor/welcome/130/edit)